# a solution to include jquery & js in the end of the html while at the same time a control which is included in the middle requires $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

i am building a website using asp.net mvc and jquery.
as a best practice its known that including javascript should be done at the end of the html page.
so i basically include jquery.js and other js files in the end of the html before the /body tag.
now i have some controls which are included in the page as partials. and they need to add functionally to $(document).ready.
but i write the code as a script tag in the partial then the jquery library wont be even included at that time and i cant include this javascript at the end of the html from within the partial. since the partial is included in the middle of the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move all javascript in single file(you may exclude jQuery file) and move it to the bottom.

If you are talking of good practice then, then writing inline javascript is not a good practice too.

So I would suggest move all your java script to single file,there are many tools available that merge multiple javascript files and crunch them, use those!!

**Edit1**

You may try this:

```
//define this at before body (or at the beginning of body)
var arrReadyCollection = [];
```

Inside controllers:

```
arrReadyCollection.push(site.module.Dialog_AcceptChanges);
arrReadyCollection.push(some_thing_Else);
```

At the end, after jQuery file

```
for (i=0;i<arrReadyCollection.length; i++)
{
     var fn= arrReadyCollection[i];
     $(document).ready(fn);
}
```

**Note**: this is not recommended way, its just  way you can solve your problem

Comment: i cant move all my javascript into a single file. the already have all my javascript in a single file except the $(document).ready part which actully dont contain code but contain the name of hte function that will execute on the $document.ready of each control. if i moved all that to a single file i would end up executing code for all controls even which are not included on the given page.

Comment: @Karim your problem is the design of your partials

Comment: @Karim your partial views have code in them. They shouldn't use a feature detection library to run and load your code. Your partials should just be HTML.

Comment: the only code in the partial is $(document).ready(site.module.Dialog_AcceptChanges). the site.module.Dialog_AcceptChanges function is defined in the global js file

Comment: and what is a feature detection library?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a javascript loader like [LABjs](http://labjs.com/).

You can use it to run javascript when certain libraries are loaded and run.

```
<head>
  <script src="lab.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    // $LAB uses async loading, no need to deferr to the end of body
    // keeping a reference to the $LAB deferred is important, so we can
    // use it from within partials (see below)
    myPage.$LAB = $LAB
      .script('someScript.js')
      .script('someOtherScript.js')
      .wait(function () {
        // your scripts are loaded!
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

In your partials you can hook into LABjs, eg like this:

```
<script>
  myPage.$LAB.script('jQuery.js').wait(function () {
    // jQuery was loaded!
    // if jQuery was loaded already by another partial or your main layout
    // it will not be loaded again, but the callback will fire immediately!
  });
</script>
```

That beeing said you really should follow the advice given by Praveen and tie your javascript files up as much as possible. Each request to your server will cost time and decrease the responsivness of your website.

Comment: this seems like a good idea, the only problem is having to include yet another library :(

Comment: Sure, but a) LABjs will speed up and streamline your entire javascript loading and b) its roughly 5k minified (before gzipped). If your javscript loading requirements are complex enough (which I think they are) this should be an acceptable overhead.

Comment: well will consider this option although dont like to include yet another js library because i try to minimize the number of include js.

Answer (score 1):

Either fix your "control" files so that they don't require inline JavaScript, or else include jQuery at the top of the file.

You could also write a small "$" function of your own that you'd include *before* jQuery (and at the top). However, you'd be better off fixing those controls anyway.

Comment: its not possible to fix the controls since they use jquery as a way of interaction, basicaly fixing my controls is not using jquery for all controls. i dont think that writing a small "$" is easy :)

Comment: Well you don't have any other choices, unfortunately. If that's the way your controls were written and you can't change them, then your pages require jQuery to be loaded before the `<body>`.

Comment: i still thinking of other ways to fix this problem. i though of including an array of functions to be executed at the start of hte page (normal array not jquery) and then at the end after jquery is include i will loop this array and execute it in the $(document).ready , but i am trying to find a better solution

Comment: I like that soluion of yours. It's easy, slim, simple.

Comment: @Daneil Baulig: which solution are you talking about?

Comment: The array thingy. You would propably want to wrap it up a bit and have it provide its own methods for adding functions and running them, but it would be just a few lines of code and provide a acceptable solution.

Comment: @Daneil Baulig: well right now i am considering another solution , server side, basically i will save this array in the PageData property and then at the end of the layout page i will output the content as javascript to be executed on $(document).ready

Comment: This is an option, however, this will make it harder to load partials by ajax and have them run their ready functions nevertheless. If this is not a required feature you might simply go with the server side solution.

Comment: @Daneil Baulig:good point, but for me this is not a requirement yet so i will go for the server side solution, i ended up using context.items instead of PageData but this is a minor difference :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Another possible solution would be to add a script tag dynamically from within the partial. This however could get messy if you want to run more than a few lines of code, eg:</strike>

```
<script>
  var script = docuement.createElement('script');
  script.innerHTML = "$(document).ready(function () { doSomething(); });";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

This should run after the jQuery (which should be already somewhere at the end of the body) was loaded and run.

**UPDATE:**
This does not work, I assumed that inserting script elements in a DOM that wasn't ready yet wouldn't execute before the DOM is ready.

Comment: well i need only to run 1 line of code. but i dont understand why this code will work? i understand that $(document).ready wont be defined too in the code .

Comment: It doesn't. I screwed up, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use [CDN's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/21/using-cdns-to-improve-web-site-performance.aspx) and quit obsessing about doubtful optimization. From the excellent [jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/) book, sec 1.22

> NOTE For performance reasons, script blocks can also be placed at the bottom
>   of the document body, though modern browsers make the performance
>   difference rather moot. The important concept is to avoid embedding behavioral
>   elements within the structural elements.

Comment: well this is not what all say about best practice to include javascript in the bottom

Comment: <blockquote>though modern browsers make the performance difference rather moot</blockquote> This is nonesense. The performance difference really is about the speed of your connection. When a script tag is encountered browser will stop parsing  the document, download the script and execute it. On a modern connection this delay is mostly not noticeable, but on a slow connection (mobile anyone?) this **is** noteable. If you have your script tags in the documents head, people will see a blank screen for how long it takes to load and run the scripts.